# How To Clear Image cache or any cache in AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Hi All can any one help me out how to clear the cache in AFNetworking.

I used to have old version of AFNetworking and i see that it has been updated, Can any body help me out how to clean the cache for AFnetworking.

Previously it was something like this

```
SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
[imageCache clearMemory];
[imageCache clearDisk];
[imageCache cleanDisk];
```

Comment: SDImageCache is from the SDWebImage project, not AFNetworking.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using AFNetworking, I recently implemented a little workaround to remove the image from the cache.

#### Look in the file "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

Under `@interface UIImageView (AFNetworking)`, add the following:

`- (void)clearImageCacheForURL:(NSURL *)url;`

And Under `@protocol AFImageCache`, add:

`- (void)clearCachedRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;`

#### Next, open "UIImageView+AFNetworking.m"

Under `@implementation UIImageView (AFNetworking)`, add the following:

```
- (void)clearImageCacheForURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    UIImage *cachedImage = [[[self class] sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:request];
    if (cachedImage) {
        [[[self class] sharedImageCache] clearCachedRequest:request];
    }
}
```

Almost done! Now just add the following below `@implementation AFImageCache`:

```
- (void)clearCachedRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    if (request) {
        [self removeObjectForKey:AFImageCacheKeyFromURLRequest(request)];
    }
}
```

And you're good to go! Now when you need to clear a particular image url from the cache, just call `[imageView clearImageCacheForURL:imgURL];`

Comment: Hi, I found this workaround does not work for UIButton+AFNetworking, is there any way to remove image cache for UIButton ?

Comment: @bachnok can you please tell me what is imgURL in last line ?

Comment: @Abha If you're trying to clear the cache for an image from something like `http://example.com/image.jpg`, then you would call: `[imageView clearImageCacheForURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"]]`

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ

> Does AFNetworking have any caching mechanisms built-in?
>
> AFNetworking takes advantage of the caching functionality already
>   provided by NSURLCache and any of its subclasses.
>
> We recommend you try out Pete Steinberger's fork of SDURLCache, which
>   provides disk caching, which is not otherwise implemented by
>   NSURLCache on iOS. You may find it useful to set
>   ignoreMemoryOnlyStoragePolicy to YES for the SDURLCache instance,
>   which will ensure that images will be cached to disk more consistently
>   for offline use (which, as reported in the SDURLCache README, iOS 5
>   supports, but only for http, so it still remains a good option if you
>   want to support iOS 4 or https)

I would also see this question:
[How To Disable AFNetworking Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968050/how-to-disable-afnetworking-cache)

Also this:
[AFNetworking and caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025964/afnetworking-and-caching)

> The moment you activate the NSURLCache you can specify it's maximum
>   size. You can also clear the cache by calling the
>   removeAllCachedResponses or removeCachedResponsesForRequest methods.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using AFNetworking using cocoaPods then you can do this by making a category of UIImageView (clearCache)

```
        - (void)clearImageCacheForURL:(NSURL *)url {
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

UIImage *cachedImage = [[[self class] sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:request];
if (cachedImage) {
    [self clearCached:[[self class] sharedImageCache] Request:request];
}
}

- (void)clearCached:(NSCache *)imageCache Request:(NSURLRequest *)request {
if (request) {
    [imageCache removeObjectForKey:[[request URL] absoluteString]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AFNetworking3.0 through cocoapods, then use below code by creating category for UIImageView.

```
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFImageDownloader.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFAutoPurgingImageCache.h>

+ (void)clearImageCacheForURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    id <AFImageRequestCache> imageCache = [[self class] sharedImageDownloader].imageCache;
    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache imageforRequest:request withAdditionalIdentifier:nil];
    if (cachedImage) {
        [self clearCached:imageCache Request:request];
    }
}

+ (void)clearCached:(AFAutoPurgingImageCache *)imageCache Request:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    if (request) {
        [imageCache removeImageforRequest:request withAdditionalIdentifier:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AFImageDownloader *imageDownloader = [AFImageDownloader   defaultInstance];

NSURLCache *urlCache = imageDownloader.sessionManager.session.configuration.URLCache;

[urlCache removeAllCachedResponses];

[imageDownloader.imageCache removeImageWithIdentifier:url];
```

this will help to remove image in cash. url is the image url that needs to remove